# An ActionController::UnknownFormat occurred in sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise

I am receiving the below error for my rails app via Exception Notification gem that sends an email.

The app has devise for authentication and there is a /users/sign_in path
The www.example.com (fake) domain is not ours, but for some reason it is making get requests against our app at that path that is causing an exception. I can visit the /users/sign_in path of our app and I will see the signin page. We have recently changed isp's and received a new ip and there might be a dns config somewhere that has not updated and is sending the other domain to our ip. I have tried to simulate the error locally by making a curl get request to the app in development with the parameters below but also get the html of the signin page back (no exception).

curl GET "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in/?action=new&controller=sessions"

My question is how would I simulate this error using curl (or any other means)?

> An ActionController::UnknownFormat occurred in sessions#new:

ActionController::UnknownFormat

---

### Request:

- URL        : http://www.example.com/users/sign_in
- HTTP Method: GET
- IP address : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
- Parameters : {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"sessions"}
- Timestamp  : 05/08/2015 06:20
- Server : XXX
- Rails root : /home/deploy/rails/XXX
- Process: 9618

---

### Session:

- session id: nil
- data: #

---

### Environment:

- HTTP_ACCEPT                                    : Accept: */*
- HTTP_CONNECTION                                : close
- HTTP_HOST                                      : www.example.com
- HTTP_REFERER                                   : http://www.example.com/
- HTTP_USER_AGENT                                : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; WebSaver; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
- HTTP_VERSION                                   : HTTP/1.0
- HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR                           : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
- HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO                         : http
- ORIGINAL_FULLPATH                              : /users/sign_in
- ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME                           :
- PATH_INFO                                      : /users/sign_in
- QUERY_STRING                                   :
- REMOTE_ADDR                                    : 127.0.0.1
- REQUEST_METHOD                                 : GET
- REQUEST_PATH                                   : /users/sign_in
- REQUEST_URI                                    : /users/sign_in
- ROUTES_51525820_SCRIPT_NAME                    :
- SCRIPT_NAME                                    :
- SERVER_NAME                                    : www.example.com
- SERVER_PORT                                    : 80
- SERVER_PROTOCOL                                : HTTP/1.0
- SERVER_SOFTWARE                                : Unicorn 4.8.3

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with `Accept` header (on the client's side).

You can simulate it with `-H` option:

```
curl -XGET -H "Accept: /" "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in/"
```

No need for `action=new&controller=sessions` part: there parameters are filled in by your routes.

Comment: Thanks @EugZol, just curios - it does not throw the same exception then.         `ActionController::UnknownFormat
actionpack (4.1.12) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb, line 440`